# Image quality in "Web Page, Filtered"

Tags: html, vba, ms-word

This is an important issue and I would be grateful for a solution.

I convert a document (RTF) with several embedded images to HTML with Word 2010. The original quality of all images is 200 dpi. When saving as "Web Page, Filtered", all images are reduced to 96 dpi, despite of what I set in the "Save As" dialog -> Tools -> Web Options -> Pictures -> Pixels per inch. I would like to keep the original image quality.

Setting `ActiveDocument.WebOptions.PixelsPerInch` with VBA is also ignored. Note that other options, e.g., `ActiveDocument.WebOptions.AllowPNG` work fine.

When I save as "Web Page" (without Filtered; VML enabled) the images are saved in original quality. However, since the image names are numbered differently, I cannot simply copy the images to the filtered version. Matching the images by hand is not an option.

Any help would be appreciated! 
Please do not suggest other Word/RTF to HTML converters - I have tried several and the results were not satisfactory for my document.

Note that I have also posted this in [Microsoft Answers](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wordcreate/thread/4c860944-c627-4fed-afd4-a7473ab1dee6), but did not get an answer yet.
There is a similar but unanswered topic on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514060/why-doesnt-saveas-use-correct-pixelsperinch-in-macro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news - this is *by-default* for Filtered webpage saves in Word. All mso tags are removed and it's made as small as possible by lowering the DPI to 96.

Comment: with the difference being that removing the mso tags does not affect the user experience on the site, unlike reducing image quality :/ thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Tools->Options->General->Web Options->Pictures

Answer (score 2):

I met this or similar problem too when trying to save to HTML a textbook manuscript with elaborate graphical figures: they would get dithered badly, messing up all fine line art and type.  Completely by chance I found a solution that worked for me: Save it as IE 6.0 HTML rather than the default IE 4.0 HTML.  (That can be adjusted e.g. via the Tools menu of the Save As dialog: Save As... -> Tools (in the top right corner) -> Web Options.)  This way the images are saved as PNG not GIF and, quite magically, that also makes the Word image renderer do a much better job for the same DPI!