# How to extract shapes, and Microsoft graphs from word as images using python?

Tags: python, image, ms-word

I want to extract shapes, graphs, and basically anything that is not a text as an image, (any format doesn't matter). I was able to extract images using this line and it works fine.

```
from docx2python import docx2python
doc_result = docx2python('someWord.docx')
doc_result.save_images(r'c:\filename\')
```

but for other types of graphics, such as graphs and shapes, it doesn't work.

I found a previous question on here, that says extract the document as a html webpage, but that doesn't work a work for me as it doesn't give anything useful.

Comment: incase anyone comes across this in the future, just save as a filtered webpage and follow this post to get actually good quality images not the horrible default ones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983264/image-quality-in-web-page-filtered